# How to Bind the selected Dropdown value in Ag grid on click of edit button in javascript

Tags: javascript

On click of edit button am not getting the selected value ,am getting default value in dropdown on page refresh.once i edit and update and again click on edit am getting proper values ,but on page refresh values are not binding
Kindly let me know how can i get selected value in dropdown in ag grid.

```
const serviceCodeMapping = {
    1: 'Pending',
    2: 'Reconciled',
    3: 'Difference unresolved',
    4: 'Difference resolved',
};



{
        headerName: "Status", editable: true, field: "statusId",
        cellEditor: 'agSelectCellEditor',
        cellEditorParams: {
            values: serviceStatusCode,
        },
        filterParams: {
            valueFormatter: function (params) {
                return lookupValue(serviceCodeMapping, params.value);
            },
        },
        valueFormatter: function (params) {
            return lookupValue(serviceCodeMapping, params.value);
        },
            valueSetter: function (params) {
                // Check if the cell is being edited
                if (params.node && params.node.isEditing()) {
                    // Skip setting default value if cell is being edited
                    return false;
                }
            }
    },

suppressClickEdit: true,
    editType: "fullRow",


        onRowEditingStarted: (params) => {
            params.api.refreshCells({
                columns: ['action'],
                rowNodes: [params.node],
                force: true,
            });
        },
```